# Adicionar CheckBox dinamicamente

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho um projeto onde ao clicar num botão pretendo pegar no texto de 3 `TextBox` diferentes e adicioná-los a uma `CheckBox`.

Até aí tudo bem, o problema surge quando quero adicionar estas `CheckBox` automáticas, para o utilizador adicionar mais linhas.

Tenho aqui um exemplo do que ele vai introduzir numa `TextBox`:

```
CheckBoxLinhas.Text = "Quantidade: " + TextBoxQuantidade.Text + " Artigo: " + TextBoxArtigo.Text + " Valor: " + TextBoxValor.Text;
```

Como posso então criar as `CheckBoxes` automáticas?

Comment: como assim automáticas?

Comment: @RafaelFerreira por código, ao clicar no botão ele cria uma ChechBox na WebForm

Comment: Você só precisa adicionar ao evento click desse botão um método para criar esse checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar um observable array do [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html) para fazer isso.

```js
var ViewModel = function(){
  self = this;
  //inicializa a lista de checkboxs vazia
  self.listaCheckBox = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  
  self.adicionaCheckBox = function(){
   self.listaCheckBox.push("checkbox"); 
   }
   
}

$(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = new ViewModel();

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-bind="click:$root.adicionaCheckBox">Adicionar CheckBox</button>
 <ul   data-bind="foreach: $root.listaCheckBox()">
   <li>
   <input type="checkbox"/><p class="form-control-static" data-bind="text: $data"></p>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: O código executa perfeitamente aqui no site, mas sou um bastante novo em asp.net e não entendi muito bem onde tenho que implantar esse código.

Comment: Este é uma biblioteca javascript que você usaria no seu html. A ideia é que você carregue as informações do seu servidor, trataria suas informações na view e então ao clicar em um botão "salvar" por exemplo você mandaria as informações de volta para o servidor.

Comment: Complementando meu comentário anterior, para isso você teria que passar o seu Model para o knockoutJS o que pode ser feito de diversas formas. [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628938/best-practice-on-passing-mvc-model-to-knockoutjs) você encontra uma boa discussão sobre isso.

Comment: Certo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!